# How to open 4 urls in separate tabs with one click

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

Is there a way I can create one clickable link to open 4 different URL's as Browser tabs?

I tried to get it to work with window.open but can't figure out how to get multiple urls each on a new tab.

For example

`<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://google.com'); window.open('http://yahoo.com');">Click to open Google and Yahoo</a>`

Thanks for your help

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4907843/4688321

Comment: Browser probably going to block the second call. If you use chrome check right of the bar

Answer (score 0):

Your link is working for me.
Please check if your Browser blocks the tab-creation (block-icon in the toolbar).

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get it to work with 3 more urls, so having multiple window.open?

Comment: My apologies, yes that work by just adding new window.opens for each url

`<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://google.com'); window.open('http://yahoo.com'); window.open('http://bing.com'); window.open('http://duckduckgo.com');">Click to open Search Engines</a>`

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment above, I was actually doing it right, it was the browser stopping it from working, enabling popups fixed it.

Multiple window.open's is what I needed to use, e.g.

`<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://google.com'); window.open('http://yahoo.com'); window.open('http://bing.com'); window.open('http://duckduckgo.com');">Click to open Search Engines</a>`